# How can I customize my kernel configuration?

Tags: 11.04, kernel

How can I customize my kernel configuration? I mean use same kernel version as Ubuntu offered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to recompile the kernel to change the configuration.  Some configurations are known incompatible with Ubuntu userspace: these are documented in the enforce file.  Self-built kernels are typically not supported by Ubuntu Developers, so take care when building such kernels.

The documentation with the procedure you ought follow is at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Comment: In that page , I can not understand the following lines "Since Ubuntu Lucid (10.04) the image postinst no longer runs the initramfs creation commands. Instead, there are example scripts provided that will perform the task. These scripts will work for official kernel images as well. " I use 11.04 . I do NOT do this step . But I can boot with new kernel . What do those lines mean ? Thanks

Comment: From wha I can tell, if you have the right other packages installed, you don't need these entries, because they will be provided by the other packages (e.g. initramfs-tools adds scripts for creation/removal of initramfs, for properly installed kernels).  On the other hand, if you're constructing a system from almost nothing, this may not be the case, and you'd need extra scripts.

Comment: "Since Ubuntu Lucid (10.04) the image postinst no longer runs the initramfs creation commands." ---- I use 11.04. Do I need to do this ? Thanks

Comment: If it works without it, as you describe, you don't need to do it (11.04 is two releases newer than 10.04).  Some people may have more heavily customised systems, and may find that they are not generating an initramfs automatically, preventing boot.  In this case, they may need to force the generation through a manual script.